# Rails-Heroku-SASS Syntax Errors For File

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sass

My repo [SelfFunder](https://github.com/fardeenrahaman/selffunder)works perfectly fine at my local machine. When I am deploying on [Heroku](http://dry-wildwood-2015.herokuapp.com/), I observe the errors as shown below:

```
Error compiling CSS asset

Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: homepage/key_points.
Load paths:
/app/app/assets/images
/app/app/assets/javascripts
/app/app/assets/stylesheets
/app/vendor/assets/javascripts
/app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/images
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-3.0.4/app/assets/javascripts
(in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss:3)

/app/app/assets/stylesheets/homepage.scss:3
```

I identified the path and observed that **homepage/key_points** is residing under the following path on my local machine:

> /views/preorder/homepage/_key_points.html.erb

Upon modifying the contents of **homepage.scss** (***as shown below***), Heroku still throws up the same error.

> @import "preorder/homepage/key_points";

Appreciate if someone can guide where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed. I overlooked **/assets/stylesheets/homepage** directory. It had some ***.css.scss*** files which upon renaming to **.scss** fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your intention there, but you are trying to import a HTML file into a CSS file, which would produce broken CSS if it were successful.

And you can only import files for assets from [certain locations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) (`app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets`).

In your case, the clue is on `/app/app/assets/images`. Notice the double `app` there. First, please follow the [guide on setting up assets compilation for Rails 4 on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4).

You seem to be missing `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` on your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Hi htanata, that doesn't work on the local machine itself as the CSS goes missing.

Comment: @fr_muses I've updated my answer. You probably need to add `homepage.css` to `config.assets.precompile`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @fr_muses Hold on, I think I see what's wrong with it. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I got the issue fixed. I overlooked /assets/stylesheets/homepage directory. It had some *.css.scss files which upon renaming to *.scss fixed the issue.

Thanks for helping out anyways.